# Is there a way to define postgres range partition tables using inequality signs to limit values?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to define postgres range partition tables using inequality signs to limit values?

my table is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.products_locations (
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    product_id UUID NOT NULL,
    latitude NUMERIC NULL,
    longitude NUMERIC NULL,
    CONSTRAINT product_location_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, latitude, longitude), -- Include latitude and longitude in the primary key
    CONSTRAINT products_locations_product_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES public.products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) PARTITION BY RANGE (latitude, longitude);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_northwest PARTITION OF public.products_locations
    FOR VALUES FROM (0, -180) TO (90, 0);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_northeast PARTITION OF public.products_locations
    FOR VALUES FROM (0, 0) TO (90, 180);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_southwest PARTITION OF public.products_locations
    FOR VALUES FROM (-90, -180) TO (0, 0);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_southeast PARTITION OF public.products_locations
    FOR VALUES FROM (-90, 0) TO (0, 180);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_ocean PARTITION OF public.products_locations
    DEFAULT;
```

Unfortunately the execution of the partitions creation scripts will fail because some of the boundaries will overlap.

I am looking for a way to define these partitions using inequality sign so that I can specify eg: latitude >= 0 in one partition and latitude < 0 in another one.

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: You can have a four-way partitioning like this if you just layer two-way partitioning: partition the main table only by latitude, then partition the sub-partitions by longitude.

Comment: As a side-note, instead of holding lat/lon as a pair of `numeric`s that you need to handle on your own, you can keep them as proper PostGIS [`geometry(point)`](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html) or even `geography` type and gain access to highly optimised geospatial processing [functions](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). Or at least, you can give the [built-in PostgreSQL `point` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html) a shot and at least have a subset of what PostGIS offers.

Comment: If those are coordinates of actual locations on the globe, slicing by the prime meridian (longitude of `0`) needlessly splits eight countries, because it happens to run right through them. You can instead find how your points are distributed with `ST_ClusterKMeans()` and partition them based on that, in groups of things that are close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use inequality operators: the lower bound is always compared with `>=` and the upper bound with `<`.

Your partitioning scheme won't work at all like you think it does. Consider that `(45, 45)` is between `(0,-180)` and `(90,0)`, because lexicographical ordering of pairs is used.

You'd have to use subpartitioning to achieve what you want: the first level creates two partitions based on latitude, and they are each partitioned into two partitions based on longitude (or vice versa). However, I cannot conceive of any benefit of such a partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting the doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-OVERVIEW-RANGE)

> Each range's bounds are understood as being inclusive at the lower end and exclusive at the upper end.

But you can easily have a four-way partitioning like this if you just layer two-way partitioning: split the main table only by `latitude`, then divide the sub-partitions by `longitude`. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/RenWTdx8)

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.products(id uuid PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO public.products SELECT gen_random_uuid() RETURNING *;

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations (
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    product_id UUID NOT NULL,
    latitude NUMERIC NULL,
    longitude NUMERIC NULL,
    -- Include latitude and longitude in the primary key
    CONSTRAINT product_location_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, latitude, longitude),
    CONSTRAINT products_locations_product_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id) 
      REFERENCES public.products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) PARTITION BY RANGE (latitude);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_north 
  PARTITION OF public.products_locations
  FOR VALUES FROM (0) TO (90) PARTITION BY RANGE (longitude);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_south 
  PARTITION OF public.products_locations
  FOR VALUES FROM (-90) TO (0) PARTITION BY RANGE (longitude);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_northwest 
  PARTITION OF public.products_locations_north
    FOR VALUES FROM (-180) TO (0);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_northeast 
  PARTITION OF public.products_locations_north
    FOR VALUES FROM (0) TO (180);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_southwest 
  PARTITION OF public.products_locations_south
    FOR VALUES FROM (-180) TO (0);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_southeast 
  PARTITION OF public.products_locations_south
    FOR VALUES FROM (0) TO (180);

CREATE TABLE public.products_locations_ocean 
  PARTITION OF public.products_locations DEFAULT;
```

To try it out, you can insert some random rows and see where they end up if you ask the `insert` to keep [`returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.7) the [`tableoid` system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html#DDL-SYSTEM-COLUMNS-TABLEOID):

```sql
SELECT setseed(.42);

INSERT INTO public.products_locations
SELECT gen_random_uuid(),
       (select id from public.products limit 1),
       -90+random()*180,
       -180+random()*360
FROM generate_series(1,8)
RETURNING tableoid::regclass, latitude, longitude, id;
```

| tableoid | latitude | longitude | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| products_locations_northwest | 43.7300775544306 | -49.5105612078397 | 1da371a9-dbd2-4e6f-ba26-b77e02aee6a6 |
| products_locations_northwest | 78.5888813356226 | -156.844787891101 | deddd809-1e1e-4bc1-a7fa-292eed4ee4f1 |
| products_locations_southwest | -73.0337475055881 | -103.008814248841 | 73f79e21-6191-44b1-ac86-66ab89687bc7 |
| products_locations_southwest | -1.64238508278359 | -39.8710864519491 | bb47fcab-f77e-42f2-a00e-b3738d283a1c |
| products_locations_northeast | 13.5899319541499 | 91.4243278980029 | 623ca838-4ae8-4454-9a51-4af61ed8bc98 |
| products_locations_northeast | 12.5143606627502 | 169.002429627645 | db34ce42-1129-4873-97c6-f180d1b63b68 |
| products_locations_northeast | 60.9069283239611 | 117.893152516528 | 4523bfe6-2656-4851-856c-54c1ddc84bc0 |
| products_locations_southwest | -66.4518283698351 | -110.129153710837 | c37b256b-2e83-41d5-9029-073a92e6df9e |

Your "ocean" is actually the North Pole (because `[0,90)` range excludes the upper `90`), plus any invalid coord pair outside the -90:90,-180:180 ranges - there's nothing stopping a point (-91,181) from getting entered. You *could* add a [`check` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) to reject those but accepting and "justifying" them automatically would be preferable. [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) does that automagically:

```sql
create extension postgis;
select st_astext('point(181 91)'::geography);
```

| st_astext |
| --- |
| POINT(-179 89) |